# Values of a List don't change programmatically

Tags: java, android, list

I have an `List` called `messages` property in my Activity.In the `synchronization()`,I called `getDateMessage(upadated_at)` function.In this function value of `messages` has changed but when program go to `synchronization` `messages` list is empty.

```
private List<message_model> messages = new ArrayList<>();
private void synchronization() {
getDateMessage(upadated_at);
    Log.e("MSDF",messages.toString()+" list tostring");
}
  private void getDateMessage(String date) {
    MessengerActivity.APIInterface apiInterface = app_net.getRetrofitInstance().create(MessengerActivity.APIInterface.class);
    retrofit2.Call<List<message_model>> call = apiInterface.getMessageDate(Ptoken, date);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<message_model>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<message_model>> call, Response<List<message_model>> response) {
            if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                messages.addAll(response.body());
                Log.e("MSDF",response.body().toString()+" responsebody in call");
                Log.e("MSDF",messages.toString()+" message in call");
                Log.e("MESSAGE", "getDateMessage successful");
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<message_model>> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("MESSAGE", "getDateMessage" + t.toString());
        }
    });
}
```

And This is my logcat.

```
    09-30 14:34:53.714 10763-10763/idea.mahdi.bime E/MSDF: [] list tostring
09-30 14:34:54.104 10763-10763/idea.mahdi.bime E/MSDF: [message_model{id=33, thread_id=2, user_id=15, body='چطوری', created_at='2018-09-29 10:28:26', updated_at='2018-09-29 10:28:26', deleted_at='null'}, message_model{id=30, thread_id=2, user_id=15, body='سلام', created_at='2018-09-29 09:30:40', updated_at='2018-09-29 09:30:40', deleted_at='null'}, message_model{id=7, thread_id=2, user_id=15, body='hi', created_at='2018-09-24 09:55:46', updated_at='2018-09-24 09:55:46', deleted_at='null'}] responsebody in api
09-30 14:34:54.104 10763-10763/idea.mahdi.bime E/MSDF: [message_model{id=33, thread_id=2, user_id=15, body='چطوری', created_at='2018-09-29 10:28:26', updated_at='2018-09-29 10:28:26', deleted_at='null'}, message_model{id=30, thread_id=2, user_id=15, body='سلام', created_at='2018-09-29 09:30:40', updated_at='2018-09-29 09:30:40', deleted_at='null'}, message_model{id=7, thread_id=2, user_id=15, body='hi', created_at='2018-09-24 09:55:46', updated_at='2018-09-24 09:55:46', deleted_at='null'}] message in api
09-30 14:34:54.104 10763-10763/idea.mahdi.bime 
E/MESSAGE: getDateMessage successful
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you call getDataMessage() it performs an asynchronous call (the retrofit enqueue() method). The server will be called to get the messages in a backgroud thread, while the android application will keep in the main thread.

Therefore, `Log.e("MSDF",messages.toString()+" list tostring");` is called before the retrofit call is made, hence, there is no current data available yet. You should make sure that you are doing something with the data after it is completed loaded.

```
private List<message_model> messages = new ArrayList<>();
private void synchronization() {
getDateMessage(upadated_at);
    // Anything you put here will be called before the data (messages) is loaded.
    // Do not work with your messages here, they'll be null.
}
  private void getDateMessage(String date) {
    MessengerActivity.APIInterface apiInterface = app_net.getRetrofitInstance().create(MessengerActivity.APIInterface.class);
    retrofit2.Call<List<message_model>> call = apiInterface.getMessageDate(Ptoken, date);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<message_model>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<message_model>> call, Response<List<message_model>> response) {
            if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                messages.addAll(response.body());
                Log.e("MSDF",response.body().toString()+" responsebody in call");
                Log.e("MSDF",messages.toString()+" message in call");
                Log.e("MESSAGE", "getDateMessage successful");
                // Anything you want to do with the messages should be placed here. When you are sure the data is completed. 
                Log.e("MSDF",messages.toString()+" list tostring");
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<message_model>> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("MESSAGE", "getDateMessage" + t.toString());
        }
    });
}
```

It's worth checking `if (response.body() != null)` before doing something with it to avoid NPE.

**EDIT**

As it was asked in the comments. A good solution (Google recommends it) is to fetch the data using a view model as described in [this android dev guide article](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel).

ViewModel approach is good because:

- The data persist during configuration changes (for example, if you rotate your device, your list of messages will be still in your app).
- It does not cause memory leaks.
- You separate view data ownership from UI controller logic.

You can see the other advantages in the article.

1 - Add the view model dependecies in your build.gradle(Module:app) file

```
dependencies {
    def lifecycle_version = "1.1.1"

    // ViewModel and LiveData
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$lifecycle_version"
}
```

See [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/adding-components#lifecycle) the latest version.

2 - Create a ViewModel class

**MessageViewModel.java**

```
public class MessagesViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private MutableLiveData<List<message_model>> messagesList;
    public LiveData<List<message_model>> getMessages() {
        if (messagesList == null) {
            messagesList = new MutableLiveData<List<message_model>>();
            loadMessages();
        }
        return messagesList;
    }

    private void loadMessages() {
        MessengerActivity.APIInterface apiInterface = app_net.getRetrofitInstance().create(MessengerActivity.APIInterface.class);
        retrofit2.Call<List<message_model>> call = apiInterface.getMessageDate(Ptoken, date);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<message_model>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<message_model>> call, Response<List<message_model>> response) {
            if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                if (response.body() != null) {
                    messagesList.setValue(response.body());
                }
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<message_model>> call, Throwable t) {
            // Handle failure
        }
        });
    }
}
```

3 - Get the messages in your activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Create a ViewModel the first time the system calls an activity's onCreate() method.
        // Re-created activities receive the same MyViewModel instance created by the first activity.

        MessagesViewModel model = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MessagesViewModel.class);
        model.getMessages().observe(this, messagesList -> {
            // Do whatever you want with the list of messages.
        });
    }
}
```

Look how clean your activity is now.

Then you can implement a [SwipeRefreshLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout) if you want to allow your users to refresh the data.

If it is not enough, you can check this [ReposViewModel](https://github.com/soonsam123/Retrofit2Sample/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/soon/karat/retrofitfs/ui/ReposViewModel.java)

Finally, if calling retrofit is the main core of your app that is going to be released to the public, you should introduce MVVM approach using Dagger 2 and RxJava, as described in [this article](https://medium.com/@saquib3705/consuming-rest-api-using-retrofit-library-with-the-help-of-mvvm-dagger-livedata-and-rxjava2-in-67aebefe031d). (This is advanced)

Comment: Can I call `synchronization()` function in a `Runnable`? I want this method do every 3 seconds.

Comment: Do you want to update the list of messages every 3 seconds? Actually, what are you trying to achieve? If this retrofit calls persist for 5 seconds and you call `synchronization()`  every 3 seconds, it will request the messages twice before the first one is done. As this is an asynchronous call, if you call it 10 times, it will deliver the result 10 times, this is going to overload your app and cause a memory leak.

Comment: So what do you think is the right and optimal solution?